# how is synchronisation of data done in android?

Tags: php, android, database

I am developing an android application and i need to sync the the data from mysql database in to sqlite database.I am doing this as I need to view the data duringoffline mode.Waiting for ur valuable reply..

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use Android Sync Framework for synchronizing your data. You need to specialize the AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter class to provide a sync adapter. You will implement your algorithm for sync here and the framework will sync your data optimally: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html

Here is a sample:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

Comment: thnks for ur favourable reply anirudh